# Unix : Grep output to multiple files

Tags: unix, grep, file-handling

I want to grep the same output to multiple files. 
example : grep "some string" > file 1 and file 2,
i want this. 
Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it with `awk`

```
awk '/some string/ {print | "tee file1"}' >file2 somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

```
grep "some string" somefile | tee file1 | tee file2
```

This would redirect the result of `grep` to `file1` and `file2` and also display that on screen.

To avoid the results being displayed on the screen, you could say:

```
grep "some string" somefile | tee file1 > file2
```